# Find individual rows that exist in two different tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL tables, Table A and Table B. Table A contains one column (colA) that contains numbers. Table B contains one column (colB) that contains numbers.

```
TableA   TableB
colA     colB
----     ----
1        1
1        1
2        2
2        2
3        7
```

I want to select all values in Table A that are also in Table B. My **desired output** is:

```
Result
----
1
1
2
2
```

I tried the following query, but it gives me duplicates because each 1 in colA pairs with each 1 in colB, and each 2 in colA pairs with each 2 in ColB:

```
SELECT colA
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.colA = TableB.colB

Result
----
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
```

When I add `DISTINCT` to my `SELECT` statement, it incorrectly filters to the following, since it only shows unique values:

```
Result
----
1
2
```

How can I select my desired output (shown again below)?

```
Result
----
1
1
2
2
```

Comment: What if `tableB` only had a single `1`. Would you only want one of your `tableA` `1` rows to come through. If so, which one (or does it not matter)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull this off you are going to have to define some sort of key on which to join or compare the two tables. (Whether that is an INNER JOIN or an INTERSECT you'll still need someway to tell a distinct row from the next since you want to preserve rows in tableA as part of the output).

To generate a key that will work in the situation we can use window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY 1)` This will start at number 1 for each distinct `colA` value and start counting up for each row that shares that `colA` value. You can change the `ORDER BY 1` to `ORDER BY some_other_column` if the ordering is important.

You query becomes:

```
 SELECT colA
 FROM (SELECT colA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colA ORDER BY 1) as mykey FROM tableA) tA
      INNER JOIN (SELECT colB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colB ORDER BY 1) as mykey FROM tableB) tB
          ON tA.colA = tB.colB AND tA.myKey = tB.myKey;
```